# InvalidArgumentError in tensorflow (softmax mnist)

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I was trying to accomplish softmax regression with tensorflow, some problems occurred as below:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
>        You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1'  with dtype float [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

From above description, I understand that the problem is an argument type error. But in my code, the type of my data is same as the placeholder.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

m = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, w)+b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
tf.global_variables_initializer()

for i in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = m.train.next_batch(100)
    train_step.run({x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(y, 1), tf.arg_max(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(accuracy.eval({x: m.test.images, y: m.test.labels}))
```

**I think the problem is caused by the type of batch_xs(float32) and batch_ys(float32).**

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the fact that you're passing `y` instead of `y_` into the feed_dict of the `accuracy.eval` call.

In this way, you're overwriting the value of `y`and your placeholder `y_` is not used.

Just change the line to

```
print(accuracy.eval({x: m.test.images, y_: m.test.labels}))
```

Comment: You are right,it's my fault to pass `y` instead of `y_` into the feed_dict of the `accuracy.eval` call.Thanks a lot.